# Resposta POST vem vazia

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

To fazendo uma requisição POST na minha API pelo meu projeto angular e só vem vazio o resultado, sendo que pelo postman vem os dados correto.

service.ts :

```
teste(user) {    

    return this.http.post(`api/home`, user)
  }
```

teste.component.ts:

```
ok(user){           
    this.loginServ.teste(user)
      .subscribe(data => {
        let retorno = (data as any)
        console.log(retorno);
      })
  }
```

Retorno só vem vazio e eu não consigo entender o pq disso.
Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: porque não usar o .then() ao invés do .subscribe()?

Comment: continua com o problema usando o .then()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no lugar de:

```
teste(user) {    

    return this.http.post(`api/home`, user)
  }
```

Resolvi assim:

```
teste(user) {    

    return this.http.post(`api/home`,  {user:user})
  }
```

Comment: depois de mil tentativas, acaba que o problema é resolvido com uma solução simples como essa, muito bom +1

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você está retornando uma *Promise*, então deve ser usado o método `.then()` na requisição, o método `.subscribe()` é para *Observables*.

**Service**

```
function teste(user) {    

return this.http.post(`api/home`, user);
```

}

**Para Promises**

```
ok(user){           
    this.loginServ.teste(user)
      .then(success);

    function success(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
}
```

**Para Observables**

```
ok(user){           
    this.loginServ.teste(user)
      .subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

---

**Promises vs Observables**

Promises - Promises lidam com eventos sigulares quando uma operação assíncrona tem sucesso ou falha.

Observable - Um Observable é como uma *Stream* e permite passar 0 ou mais eventos quando o response é retornado e também chamar funções ou *callbacks* para esses eventos.

Comment: nao funciona. 'cannot name success'

Comment: @Maria editado.

Comment: continua dando erro. 'Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'

Comment: perfeito, se trata de um Observable então, vou fazer uma edição e te menciono novamente no comentário. Da próxima vez que for perguntar tente fornecer mais código ou mais contexto para a pergunta, pois assim fica mais difícil ajudar e isso só faz demorar mais pra te ajudarmos a resolver seu problema. ;)

Comment: Ah, sim. tendi. obrigada mesmo

Comment: @Maria veja se o código a seguir te ajuda, isso pode ser um problema de escopo, se for confirmado posso te explicar no chat o que pode ter ocorrido

Comment: Continua vindo vazio o retorno

Comment: @Maria você já debuggou para confirmar se o problema é no angular mesmo? O retorno pode estar vindo vazio já do backend

Comment: eu debugguei e aparentemente ta tudo correto, mas continua vindo vazio o retorno, como se tivesse algo sendo enviado errado

Comment: nao sei se isso pode ser algo, mas quando debbuguei agora deu erro 'Exception has occurred: number' , 'Exception has occurred: SyntaxError
SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1', 'Exception has occurred: SyntaxError'